# What could be most indicative icon for "Blog"?

Tags: icon, representation

I'm really stuck thinking on what could be the most friendly way to represent "Blog" as icon. Google search led me [here](https://thenounproject.com/term/blog/16343/) but it doesn't indicate a blog completely.

I have designed this:

[image: OPs Blog Icon]

but it doesn't look promising either. It more looks like writing on a sheet of paper. How do I make changes in this so as to look like writing on a "blog".

P.S.: I'm designing icons for a website where there are links for 'Wiki', 'Forum', 'Blog' etc and those links are supposed to be icons.

Comment: It may help others if you list what words define "blog" to you. I think both your Google result and the icon you've created both represent blog. Why do you think they don't?

Comment: @Scott Actually I want to enhance this icon to make it more friendlier. For eg: I also had to create icon for 'news', it was easy to make a "Newspaper" kind of icon.. but I also added a "Coffee Cup" in that. So it looked even better and friendlier. I just want to tweak my blog icon so that people can recognize it even without the word "blog" written below the icon.

Comment: I understand Ravi, but what I don't know is how anyone here will be able to understand what you perceive as "friendlier". That's a **very** ambiguous term.

Comment: What about a pencil with the Blog logo you linked? Maybe would be a good idea to support the logo.

Answer (score 2):

You could try with something like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi Gilberto, welcome to GD.SE! I edited your answer to fit our usual style. Please feel free to re-edit.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding was that there was one. A quick google search shows that it seems to be[a bauhaus 'b' with similar waves coming off of it as the rss icon](http://www.google.com/search?q=blog%20icon&rls=com.microsoft%3aen-us%3aIE-Address&oe=&safe=active&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=9OTmUfH1IvKv4AOw3YGIDg&biw=1920&bih=1091&sei=9uTmUeHJL8Tj4APBj4G4Dw#imgdii=_). The icon you designed looks almost positively like an edit button or a link to open some sort of form to fill out. Be careful using a pencil symbol, this sumbol's become pretty standard for edit icons of any size.

Felt the need to add this as it's pretty interesting and obviously relevant/answers your question: http://theblogicon.com/

Comment: Oh yes I agree! Actually I already encountered the icon you directed me to.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any precedence aside from a variation of the RSS feed.

While using familiar, easily recognizable elements, you could try something simple and indicative of what a blog represents.

[image: Idea]

Here, I'm illustrating the idea that the blog is a way of communicating ideas. ("Talk about [you] ideas.")

Ask around you and try to think of what a blog means to yourself and other people. Try to do it without using words such as "the web/Internet," "online," or "journal/diary."